# how to set miliseconds to date format inside a map in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get from the backend (Firebase) an array of objects with 2 properties(url:string,timestamp{seconds: number, nanoseconds: number})
I am doing a map so I can list all the pictures with the uploaded date, but I cannot get to convert the time to valid format date to render it on the screen, this is what I am trying with no success

```
  {items.map(i => (
           <div className="card">
             <img className="card-img-top materialboxed" src={i.url} alt="" />
             <p>{new Date(i.created.seconds)}</p>
           </div>
         ))}
```

this is the output coming:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Mon Jan 19 1970 08:17:21 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (at Pictures.jsx:60)
    in div (at Pictures.jsx:58)
    in div (at Pictures.jsx:56)
    in div (at Pictures.jsx:55)
    in Pictures (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.tsx:32)
    in Switch (at App.tsx:31)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.tsx:29)
    in div (at App.tsx:28)
    in App (at src/index.tsx:22)
    in Router (at src/index.tsx:21)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot render a Date-Object directly. Convert it to a string first. (maybe with `new Date(...).toString()`)

Comment: it worked. Thanks! honestly I did not thought I was trying to render an object, I havel learn something new today!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, you cannot render `object` in JSX like that. You always need to render a single value. When you write:

```
<p>{new Date(i.created.seconds)}</p>
```

You are trying to print the `Date` object, which is showing the error. To avoid that error parse the date:

```
<p>{new Date(i.created.seconds).toString()}</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this

```
function getMilliseconds(dateTime) {
    const currentDate = new Date(dateTime);
    const milliseconds = currentDate.getMilliseconds();

    return milliseconds;
}
```

Comment: What..? Why would you create a date out of milliseconds just to get the milliseconds..? You've basically just told him to run `Date.getMilliseconds()` when he already has milliseconds and wants to get a Date (which he has done, the real issue is that he can't render a Date object in the template and needs to use a string)